# How to extend class with optional constructor parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a base class where I have an optional parameter with default value in the constructor:

```
export class ProvidersRepo {
  constructor(
    public tableName:string = "providers-default"
    ){}
}
```

Then I want my subclass to accept `tableName` as optional parameter and pass to the `super()`. If undefined then the `super` class should assign the dafault value for it.
Here is the subclass:

```
export class VendorRepo extends ProvidersRepo{
  constructor(public tableName?: string){
    super(tableName)
  }
}
```

But I get typescript error:

> Class 'VendorRepo' incorrectly extends base class 'ProvidersRepo'.
> Types of property 'tableName' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUoQG4CWAJsFGgErCRwDeAUHIhAHZoxQCuCM0AFA4zhgOAIyQEEcGCjHAAcigC2wAFxsoBZgHM4AXjgAiMLkIkyAWigoiENKjznFKDc3zmUSVM2AGBjAJQ0AL50IXSgkLCIqBhwAGrAzDZQlNSgMIlEmDj4xKQUVBD0jAgs6lw8ULzCYhJSMkjySsAA-Cpw6ppagX4dHGCkvNKyCsr%20AiFBQA)

The main idea is when I instanciate the `VendorRepo` and not provide `tableName` to have it set to the default value `"providers-default"`. But when I do specify a value for `tableName` I want the object to be initiated with that value.

Comment: Don't use a [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) in the subclass.  By writing `public tableName?: string` you are telling TS to explicitly set `tableName` to the passed-in value, which might be `undefined`, after `super()` is called.  There's no reason to do that; just remove `public` there and [things will start working](https://tsplay.dev/WGGnoW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?